# Bootstrap navbar toggle not in sync with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made my own hamburger animation based of of this codepen:
http://codepen.io/dalton/pen/YXZGry

As I prefer the animation to be a bit slow I set:

```
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
```

It works fine, i.e. I have a hamburger button, when I toggle I get the single - shaped button and the navbar dropdown menu appears; So hamburger when collapsed, - button when dropdown menu visible. However when I toggle twice fast the navbar dropdown menu appears and stays but the button toggles back to a hamburger (so button 'is out of sync' now). Desired behavior is to have always hamburger when collapsed and - button when not collapsed. How can I solve this?

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/w75b4rdf/6/

Make sure to quickly double press the lines of the hamburger (somehow in this fiddle the button edges behaves 'separate' from the hamburger...?!).

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @vanburenx I added a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it will add class only when your menu is opening and remove it only when it is hiding. Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#nav-icon4').addClass('open');
    });
    $('#navbar').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#nav-icon4').removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! This works extremely well: Always in sync and both button animation (even very slow ones) and dropdown menu are nicely sensitive to fast toggles! Great, thanks!

Comment: I have change my nav to side-nav and now would like the side-nav to appear when pressing the hamburger...; the side-nav I use: http://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/sidenav/    So I would expect that I need to change the 'show.bs.collapse' but I tried several values like 'show.side-nav' etc but I can not get it working. Could you maybe help me out?

Comment: Material Design for Bootstrap is different. You have to use different method to achieve you goal. There is no `show/hide.side-nav` method in MDB. I recommend you to start a new topic for that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be controlled using a click tracker on the hamburger menu button. set `data-clicked = 0` to your button and increment it on each click. The magic part is you have to disable any change on certain click tracker situations.
Always do the hamburger menu transition when the tracker show integer `1`.

**Html**

```
<button class=".menuBtn">Menu Button</button>
```

**Jquery**

```
var btn = $('.menuBtn');
btn.click(function()) {
if ($(this).attr('data-clicked') == 0) {
    // toggle menu
}
else {
    // Do Nothing
}
}.promise().done(function(){btn.attr('data-clicked', 1)});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get it working. Is the first line of Jquery, i.e. data-clicked="0">Menu</button> correct, as it looks like html like code...?

Comment: I can not get your js code working, so I added a fiddle.