# Trigger MDBootstrap side-nav with jQuery using custom hamburger button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This was working fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/ef76gud7/

Now I would like to use MDBootstrap instead of Bootstrap and so I have to alter this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#nav-icon4').addClass('open');
    });
    $('#navbar').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#nav-icon4').removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

to work with this side-nav (using my own animated hamburger, see fiddle):
http://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/sidenav/

I can trigger the side-nav with my hamburger by adding these to my hamburger button:
data-activates="slide-out"
class="button-collapse"

But then I loose the animation, since obviously the bootstrap navbar collapse is no longer shown.

How can I have my hamburger animation together with the new side-nav? Probably the cited jQuery code needs to be adjusted completely?!

So following is needed: (1) trigger MD bootstrap sidenav from another CSS button then its default one (2) the hamburger animation should stay 'in sync' with the sidenav. For instance: just using toggle it would probably loose sync as I had similar experiences before: [Bootstrap navbar toggle not in sync with dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110311/bootstrap-navbar-toggle-not-in-sync-with-dropdown-menu)

You could use this fiddle as a starting point:
http://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/rto14vzp/2/

Comments regarding the fiddle:

- ignore the JS and CSS resource panel message; i tried adding
  mdbootstrap via the resource panel and it did not work whereas
  current approach does.
- the reference to mdbootstrap (via CDN url)    refers to the free part
  of mdbootstrap (the side-nav is part of the    free package).

Comment: when you loose  animation can you make fiddle ? actually i confuse with your question

Comment: @IsmailFarooq I tried making a fiddle with a mdbootstrap side-nav. It seems mdbootstrap does not work as a fiddle (maybe because cdn urls are http instead of https).

Comment: So just add url like //www.xyz

Comment: This request doesn't really make any sense. If you have a sidenav hamburger menu and the side menu slides out, it will cover the icon before the animation can visibly occur to your user.

Comment: @staypuftman YES it does, since obviously it will NOT be covered. Not 100% "material design", but it is exactly what I want.

Comment: I mocked this up but every time I tried using md-bootstrap in this way, it predictably covered up the menu icon. I guess I could position it...let me see.

Comment: How about just using one of css framework then apply your custom hamburger menu?

Comment: @claudios I do not understand your 'one of css framework'; could you be more specific maybe?

Comment: @claudios I added a little to my question to make it hopefully somewhat more clear.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Made a fiddle, see edited question.

Comment: @musicformellons you want to toggle this http://jsfiddle.net/rto14vzp/3/ navbar like mdbootstrap side navbar, right ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Yes, so your fiddle but then with side-nav going left-right and viceversa not topdown viceversa.

Comment: ok do you want side nav all the time or just after mobile version (after 768px) ?

Comment: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Comment: @IsmailFarooq side-nav all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct answer to your question is that you need to chain the button animation and `sideNav()` opening triggers together with one jQuery statement. If you add `.nav-icon-line` to your spans, that would look like this:

```
  $("#nav-icon4, .nav-icon-line").click(function() {
    $("#nav-icon4").addClass('open');
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  });
```

There is a lot more going on here that I can't really get into because the source of `sideNav()` isn't freely available with the framework you are using.

Something else to consider:

You'd need to reset the hamburger animation in the same way by using `removeClass()`. I'm not really sure how that would work because `sideNav()` is a black box. From what I can see, `sideNav()` seems to hide the sidebar when you click outside of it; figure out what function controls that and put `$("#nav-icon4").removeClass('open');` into the function.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/yOEJGo) (not fully functional yet, depends on figuing out what's happening inside of `sideNav`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would need some time to find out if that works. My bounty expires in 21 hrs. Do you know whether you will receive the bounty when I accept your answer after that 'deadline'?

Comment: Not really sure. Post the sideNav JS code - that would help me (and others) be able to test. I'll update my answer with the partially working Codepen (I'd need to dig into the sideNav function to finish this).

Comment: Ok, I added a fiddle. Referencing MDBootstrap works in it, so you should be able to work on it.

Comment: Yeah but I need a non-minimized version of that framework's JS so I can actually read through the functions and figure out what's going on.

Comment: You can get it here: http://mdbootstrap.com//MDB/j38gvh-128vnfu73bvc/MDB_3.3.3.zip

Comment: @musicformellons - I'm not seeing anything in this file that references the `sideNav()` behavior. This framework is so bloated on top of jquery and bootstrap - do you really need all this? Every page on your site you are loading about 500K of JS bloat. There has to be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.